# Issue generating previews and display of thumbnails in Liferay

Tags: pdf, liferay, ghostscript

I developed a portal and have added a few docx and pdf files to documents and media portlet. To generate previews I followed [This](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Preview+Generation) link. 
But the preview generation takes a lot of time, almost an hour to two for pdf files. There is no thumbnail display as well. 
Initially I used the method suggested in this link as a [temporary solution](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32350049). But later was unable to use the solution. 
Instead the time for preview generation took more time.

I checked the log files to find the following error: `03:05:56,097 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.process.ProcessUtil-8][LoggingOutputProcessor:59] GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`

Since I have more than 100 files, I cannot invest a lot of time just for preview generation. 
Liferay : liferay-ce-6.2-ga4, gs: Ghostscript 9.16(lowered to 9.14, still faced the issue.), open office 3.3, imagemagick:ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16.

How do Ix solve this?

Comment: Is there any command i can use as a background process, so that i need to refresh the page or enable and disable the imagemagick and ghostscript often. ??

Comment: Unless you have astonishingly complex PDF files, possibly involving considerable (and complicated) use of transparency, there's no way a preview should take that long with Ghostscript. The error you quote is catastrophic, and quite immediate, that exited instantly which suggests the delay is not due to Ghostscript (caveat; the real error logging may be getting discarded). If you can find out from the Liferay developers how they are invoking ImageMagick, then you can find out how ImageMagick is invoking Ghostscript. At that point, armed with a copy of the PDF I could attempt to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/util/PDFProcessorImpl.java#L446(PDFProcessorImpl )indirectly calls https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/image/GhostscriptImpl.java#L39(GhostscriptImpl)

Comment: I'm not a Java coder, I have no idea what any of that means. While I'm happy to look at the problem I need an example input file, and a Ghostscript command line invocation.

Comment: Any pdf file will work for that matter ie any pdf file will suffere this problem of late previews and thumbnails. I have no idea about the ghostscript commands, i am using it with Liferay.

Comment: I don't use Liferay or ImageMagick. I am a Ghostscript developer, if you can reproduce a problem (slow performance) with Ghostscript I'll be happy to look at it, but I can't help you with the other application(s).

Comment: Do you find any solution ? I have same problem.